# Calculating the Waiting time if only the time is in 24 hours format?

Tags: sql-server

I have the Data for different trains, I need to calculate the Waiting time if the person is waiting to take train this will be applicable if the person is taking the connecting trains  but the problem is I am having the time of arrival and departure time for all the trains for each station.

In the Image you can see the data for arrival and departure time is in the time format what I actually need is if a person is selecting the source and destination then for that route if he need to take two trains if the 1st train has start at morning `9:00:00 Am` and Departs at `23:00:00 PM` and the second train starts at `00:00:00 Am` then I need to find the waiting time which is the difference of `23:00:00PM` to `00:00:00 AM` but If in find the difference it is showing me negative number but what I need is it should consider the `00:00:00 Pm` as 2nd day and should give me the time as Positive

Current Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 
    (t1.Train_No + ',' + t2.Train_No) AS TrainSeq
    ,DATEDIFF(MI, CONVERT(TIME, t2.Arrival_Time), Convert(TIME, t1.Depature_Time)) AS Waiting_Time
FROM Rail t1
JOIN Rail t2 
    ON t2.Source_Station_Name = t1.Destination_Station_Name
    AND T2.Arrival_Time > T1.Depature_time  
WHERE t1.Source_Station_Name LIKE 'Ernakulam%'
    AND t2.Destination_Station_Name LIKE 'Agra%'
ORDER BY Waiting_Time ASC
```

"Data:

```
Train No.,Train Name,islno,station Code,Station Name,Arrival time,Departure time,Distance,Source Station Code,Source Station Name,Destination station Code,Destination Station Name,Distance
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,1,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,'00:00:00','19:50:00',0,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,64
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,2,LNL ,LONAVALA       ,'20:43:00','20:45:00',64,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,28
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,3,KJT ,KARJAT         ,'21:28:00','21:30:00',92,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,47
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,4,KYN ,KALYAN JN      ,'22:17:00','22:20:00',139,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,25
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,5,BIRD,BHIWANDI ROAD  ,'22:48:00','22:50:00',164,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,27
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,6,BSR ,VASAI ROAD     ,'23:45:00','23:50:00',191,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,72
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,7,DRD ,DAHANU ROAD    ,'01:08:00','01:10:00',263,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,51
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,8,VAPI,VAPI           ,'01:43:00','01:45:00',314,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,24
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,9,BL  ,VALSAD         ,'02:11:00','02:13:00',338,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,39
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,10,NVS ,NAVSARI        ,'03:01:00','03:03:00',377,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,29
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,11,ST  ,SURAT          ,'03:50:00','03:55:00',406,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,59
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,12,BH  ,BHARUCH JN     ,'04:39:00','04:41:00',465,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,70
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,13,BRC ,VADODARA JN    ,'05:40:00','05:45:00',535,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,36
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,14,ANND,ANAND JN       ,'06:19:00','06:21:00',571,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,18
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,15,ND  ,NADIAD JN      ,'06:39:00','06:41:00',589,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,43
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,16,MAN ,MANINAGAR      ,'07:23:00','07:25:00',632,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,3
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,17,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,'07:45:00','00:00:00',635,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,-635
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,1,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,'00:00:00','23:30:00',0,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,20
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,2,AWY ,ALUVA          ,'23:51:00','23:53:00',20,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,55
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,3,TCR ,THRISUR        ,'00:38:00','00:41:00',75,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,32
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,4,SRR ,SHORANUR JN    ,'01:30:00','01:35:00',107,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,45
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,5,TIR ,TIRUR          ,'02:14:00','02:16:00',152,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,41
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,6,CLT ,KOZHIKODE      ,'03:05:00','03:10:00',193,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,69
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,7,TLY ,THALASSERY     ,'04:02:00','04:03:00',262,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,21
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,8,CAN ,KANNUR         ,'04:35:00','04:40:00',283,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,33
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,9,PAY ,PAYYANUR       ,'05:08:00','05:10:00',316,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,29
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,10,KZE ,KANHANGAD      ,'05:35:00','05:37:00',345,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,23
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,11,KGQ ,KASARAGOD      ,'05:53:00','05:55:00',368,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,51
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,12,MAJN,MANGALORE JN   ,'07:05:00','07:15:00',419,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,36
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,13,MULK,MULKI          ,'07:44:00','07:45:00',455,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,46
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,14,UD  ,UDUPI          ,'08:40:00','08:42:00',501,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,44
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,15,KUDA,KUNDAPURA      ,'09:28:00','09:30:00',545,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,69
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,16,BTJL,BHATKAL        ,'10:20:00','10:22:00',614,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,21
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,17,MRDW,MURDESHWAR     ,'10:40:00','10:42:00',635,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,37
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,18,HNA ,HONNAVAR       ,'11:10:00','11:12:00',672,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,19
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,19,KT  ,KUMTA          ,'11:40:00','11:42:00',691,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,27
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,20,GOK ,GOKARNA ROAD   ,'12:00:00','12:02:00',718,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,50
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,21,KAWR,KARWAR         ,'12:50:00','12:52:00',768,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,82
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,22,MAO ,MADGAON        ,'14:05:00','14:25:00',850,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,16
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,23,SVM ,SANVERDAM CHUCH,'14:38:00','14:40:00',866,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,18
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,24,QLM ,KULEM          ,'15:05:00','15:10:00',884,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,59
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,25,CLR ,CASTLE ROCK    ,'16:05:00','16:10:00',943,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,24
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,26,LD  ,LONDA JN       ,'16:48:00','16:50:00',967,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,51
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,27,BGM ,BELGAUM        ,'18:55:00','19:00:00',1018,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,58
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,28,GPB ,GHATPRABHA     ,'19:58:00','20:00:00',1076,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,80
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,29,MRJ ,MIRAJ JN       ,'22:55:00','23:00:00',1156,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,7
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,30,SLI ,SANGLI         ,'23:12:00','23:15:00',1163,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,68
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,31,KRD ,KARAD          ,'00:12:00','00:15:00',1231,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,59
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,32,STR ,SATARA         ,'01:07:00','01:10:00',1290,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,145
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,33,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,'05:05:00','00:00:00',1435,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,-1435
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,1,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,'00:00:00','16:55:00',0,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,68
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,2,MSH ,MAHESANA JN    ,'17:58:00','18:00:00',68,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,65
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,3,PNU ,PALANPUR JN    ,'19:36:00','19:38:00',133,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,53
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,4,ABR ,ABU ROAD       ,'21:00:00','21:12:00',186,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,99
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,5,FA  ,FALNA          ,'22:29:00','22:31:00',285,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,66
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,6,MJ  ,MARWAR JN      ,'23:30:00','23:32:00',351,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,88
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,7,BER ,BEAWAR         ,'00:57:00','00:59:00',439,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,52
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,8,AII ,AJMER JN       ,'02:00:00','02:10:00',491,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,135
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,9,JP  ,JAIPUR         ,'04:05:00','04:15:00',626,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,187
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,10,BTE ,BHARATPUR JN   ,'06:48:00','06:50:00',813,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,54
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,11,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,'08:20:00','00:00:00',867,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,-867"
```

Comment: Please update this question with this query. Thanks Vivek.

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to show us your code. And make sure that you highlight the code and hit the `{}` button so that it shows up as *readable* code, unlike what happens when you paste code in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some sample data for this example;

```
CREATE TABLE #Times (ID int, StartTime time, EndTime time)
INSERT INTO #Times
VALUES
(1,'10:00','11:00')
,(2,'14:00','20:00')
,(3,'23:00','00:00')
,(4,'22:00','02:00')
```

The following query has your current `DATEDIFF` statement, followed by a `CASE` expression that will allow for you to check if you're running over midnight;

```
SELECT 
ID
,StartTime
,EndTime
,DATEDIFF(MI, CONVERT(TIME, StartTime), Convert(TIME, EndTime)) original
,CASE
    WHEN EndTime < StartTime 
        THEN DATEDIFF(MI, CONVERT(TIME, StartTime), Convert(TIME, EndTime)) + 1440
    ELSE DATEDIFF(MI, CONVERT(TIME, StartTime), Convert(TIME, EndTime))
END NewCalc
FROM #Times
```

The 1440 figure is the number of minutes in a day `(60 mins * 24 hours)`

The output looks like this;

```
ID  StartTime           EndTime             original    NewCalc
1   10:00:00.0000000    11:00:00.0000000    60          60
2   14:00:00.0000000    20:00:00.0000000    360         360
3   23:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    -1380       60
4   22:00:00.0000000    02:00:00.0000000    -1200       240
```

The differences are in minutes as per your example. You should really be doing the `datediff` using a `datetime` field as you may not know if you have unexpected data that may run over multiple days.

Comment: There is one clarification needed Rich, if you see my query I have TrainSeq which is the combination of two train numbers , in that case the waiting time will be (Departure time of last stop of train1 - Departure Time of the Starting stop of Train 2) how do I fetch these two departure times and use in my query?

Comment: Could you update your question with your sample data in text form please? That way I will be able to copy it out for testing.

Comment: I have changed the image in my question just have a look in the above image I am trying to find the waiting time between source station 'Ernakulam' and Destination 'Agra' , the problem I am encountering is I am not able to fetch the last departure time of 1st train

Comment: That doesn't help. I'd like to do some testing with your actual data but I'm not prepared to type it out manually from a picture. Hence the reason that I've asked you to give me your data in text form.

Comment: I have attached the data in csv format just have a look in this what I am trying to achieve is the person is travelling from ERNAKULAM to AGRA so he is taking the 3 trains , so I need to find the time he is waiting to take connecting trains

Comment: #Rich, I have one more clarification as you have mentioned in the above example , it is giving the time difference but there is one more complexity to be added as I am finding  the time diff for 2 station , lets take the train have started at 1:00 Pm and reached the other station at 1:45 PM in that case it will be 45 minutes but what my requirement says it should take 1:45 Pm as next day 1:45 Pm and calculate the time?

Comment: You're going to have to convert it to a datetime field and perform the same datediff function on that.

Comment: #Rich but I only have time in my data not date

Comment: Unless you've got a date then how do you know that the 1:45pm is the next day?

Comment: Because a train will stop at many stations lets take the train have started at 13:45PM and the train have reached on 12:15PM but in my data I have arrival time and departure time for each station, by looking at the data if  the destination station is after 00:00 then it should be considered as 2 day train

Comment: I'd suggest posting a separate question showing where you are at the moment (you can even link to this question if you like) but state that you need to calculate over days but without a date field. The comments section of this answer isn't the place to be asking these questions. You also don't need as much data, just enough to explain your question.